# Replacing nested for loops with an apply function

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am building a movie recommendation engine and the below code computes the similarity matrix.

```
data <- read.csv('movie_test.csv')

similarity <- matrix(NA, nrow(data), nrow(data))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {

for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {

if (i != j) {
  similarity[i, j] <- sum((data[i,] * data[j,]), na.rm = TRUE) / 
    (sqrt((sum(((data[i,] - data[j,] + data[j,]) * data[i,]), na.rm = TRUE))) *
       sqrt((sum(((data[j,] - data[i,] + data[i,]) * data[j,]), na.rm = TRUE))))
    }
  }
}
```

For a small dataset this works perfect. But for 900 users and 1000 movies this does not scale. I have heard that the apply set of functions works faster but I doubt even that will scale. Is there any other way I can achieve the above task without using a for loop?

Thank you so much for your suggestions!!!

Comment: they are not significantly faster, just more readable

Comment: why are you doing things like `- data[j,] + data[j,]`? Did you forget to simplify or did you code it wrong?

Comment: If it helps, it appears this is called the "reflective correlation matrix".

Answer (score 2):

This should be fast:

```
m <- as.matrix(data)
m[is.na(m)] <- 0
z <- m %*% t(m)
d <- sqrt(diag(z))
similarity <- t(t(z) / d) / d
```

The diagonal will contain `1` which seems more appropriate than `NA` but if you prefer you can always do:

```
diag(similarity) <- NA
```